# Why can't combine ajax .load and .fadeIn as a callback?

Tags: ajax, function, load, fadein

I've got an eventcalendar, and when you click on a day it loads the daily program.
But it does not fade in. The page has three divs, because the calendar shows only the actual, the previous and the next month. (div1 - prev, div2 - actual, div3 - next) but only one is visible at a time. It loads the content perfectly but not with fade. Any idea?

Thanks!

Daniel

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".freeday").click(function(){
         $("#p_div1").load("none.txt", {}, function(){ $(this).fadeIn("700");}    );
         $("#p_div2").load("none.txt", {}, function(){ $(this).fadeIn("700");}    );
         $("#p_div3").load("none.txt", {}, function(){ $(this).fadeIn("700");}    );    
      });
   });
```

Comment: My guess would be that the value of `this` isn't correct when the callback gets executed. I would check that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".freeday").click(function(){
         $("#p_div1").hide().load("none.txt", {}, function(){ $(this).fadeIn("700");}    );
         $("#p_div2").hide().load("none.txt", {}, function(){ $(this).fadeIn("700");}    );
         $("#p_div3").hide().load("none.txt", {}, function(){ $(this).fadeIn("700");}    );    
      });
   });
```

**.load()** gets a callback function that is executed when request completes.
In order to successfully **.fadeIn()** the content you should first hide the container, load the content and finally execute the **.fadeIn()** function.